# Viewing permissions in Atlassian Stash

Tags: bitbucket-server

I wonder if there is a way for an ordinary user to view the list of user permissions for a given repository in Atlassian Stash. Specifically I'm interested in who has permission to push commits to a repository.

The stuff I've been able to find seems to be about establishing permissions, for use by project administrators.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 3 types of permissions - `admin`, `write` and `read`. Only admins can see and edit the settings (which include permissions).

Comment: OK. Do I understand correctly, then, that there is no way for ordinary users to see who has write permission?

Comment: @RobertDodier nope.